# Konvajs and jQuery to fadeIn() image to stage

Tags: konvajs

I'm able to click on an image in an html page and have the image render to the Konva stage. I'm trying to fadeIn() the image using jQuery and this is where I'm stuck.

```
//FADE IN IMAGE 
$('img').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/5w5swLde/8/

I could use some help. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to `fadeIn` inserted image you may use tween via `to` method:

```
            image.setAttrs({
                node: image,
                x:10,
                y:10,
                id: id,
                draggable: true,
                opacity: 0   // invisible on adding
            });
            // append to layer
            layer.add(image);
            // fade it
            image.to({opacity: 1});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5w5swLde/9/

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was trying to achieve